# Program instanty terminated in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run a program in Java but after clicking Run I've got this

```
<terminated> Hello [Java Application] c:\\Program File\Java\jre1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
```

Here is my code

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I've read another topics about that but I didn't find the answer. All I can say is that it's not a problem with my program. It compiles and runs in Windows console but not in Eclipse. I've tried to add -vm in eclipse.ini but nothing.

EDIT: I've changed my workspace and everything starts to work. I don't know why but it worked

Answer (score 0):

COULD it be that your hello world program conflicted with any other programs you had open? Eclipse is weird like that sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I have heard eclipse sometimes fails because of crazy firewall settings.

can You check error log and tell us what error is being thrown while launching the application?